# Router in nodejs does not seem to work as I expect it

Tags: node.js, express

I am building simple app to teach myself node and I've got this problem.

Console.log is not executed at all. Do you have any idea why?

I have 404 error but nothing else. App doesnt crash, I just cant get this view.

```
 router.get('/charts/top/:exercise', function(req, res, next) {
      console.log("exercise: " + req.params.exercise);
      res.render("top", {});
    });
```

SOLUTION: Since this was in separate routes folder in charts.js file, there should not be /charts but just /top/:exercise

Comment: 404 means the route cannot be found. What's your url? Maybe you're not using it properly, or you haven't used `app.use` for the routing?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your router comes from :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
```

You will need to export this module for your server to know that these routes are handled. with the following :

```
module.exports = router;
```

Under all your routes definitions.

Now, your app just needs to call this said file with the routes to be handled.

```
var handler = require('./handler');
-Some code-
app.use('/', handler);
```

.use will set the primary pivot of the route to your router. It gives the ball to it. In this exemple, everything from / will be passed to router. If you really want to make this clean, change your router variable in your file to charts and use it in your app to everything that starts with /charts

Then in your charts file you will be able to handle /top/:exercice

You can make multiple levels of routing like this with .use to set your new point of handling.

Also, I would like to point out that you don't need "next" in your function because you do not have any callback.

Edit : And remember, if 2 routes could be handled, it will always be the first one declared to catch it. That way, declare some routes with a if else logic behind it. Giving the more specific choice first.

Comment: everything you said is done:
app.js:
var charts = require('./routes/charts');
app.use('/charts', charts);
and also in charts.js is everything done as you said 

any other idea where can be mistake?

Comment: Maybe you're putting your 404 handler before this route. This is a common mistake for people who just get started with express. Any routes should be placed before the 404 handler. In other words, the 404 handler should be placed at the very bottom of the code after all routes have been registered.